# Does the .ssh file automatically come installed on a linux system by default?

Tags: ssh

If I tell someone to look in

```
~/.ssh
```

Can I assume that that folder will always exist on a nix filesystem?  Specifically, is it always there on the standard distros of linux and MacOsx?  I'm [following the github generate ssh keys tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys), and it appears to assume that ssh is something included by default.  Is that true?

Update: apparently MAC OSX [has an ssh server installed by default, but it is not enabled.](http://bluishcoder.co.nz/articles/mac-ssh.html) according to the log by Chris Double,

> The Apple Mac OS X operating system has SSH installed by default but the SSH daemon is not enabled. This means you can’t login remotely or do remote copies until you enable it.
>
> To enable it, go to ‘System Preferences’. Under ‘Internet & Networking’ there is a ‘Sharing’ icon. Run that. In the list that appears, check the ‘Remote Login’ option.
>
> This starts the SSH daemon immediately and you can remotely login using your username. The ‘Sharing’ window shows at the bottom the name and IP address to use. You can also find this out using ‘whoami’ and ‘ifconfig’ from the Terminal application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OS X, Ubuntu, CentOS and presumably other linux distros the ~/.ssh directory does not exist by default in a user's home directory. On OS X and most linux distros the ssh-client and typically an ssh server are installed by default so that can be a safe assumption.

The absence of the ~/.ssh directory does not mean that the ssh client is not installed or that an ssh server is not installed. It just means that particular user has not created the directory or used the ssh client before. A user can create the directory automatically by successfully sshing to a host which will add the host to the client's ~/.ssh/known_hosts file or by generating a key via ssh-keygen. A user can also create the directory manually via the following commands.

`mkdir ~/.ssh
chmod 700 ~/.ssh`

To test whether an ssh client and/or server is installed and accessible on the path you can use the `which` command. Output will indicate whether the command is installed and in the current user's path.

`which ssh # ssh client
which sshd # ssh server`

Answer (score 0):

I would say no. I guess on 99% of the systems there is an ssh server running but IMHO in most cases you need to install that software on your own.

And even if it is installed, the directories are created on the first usage of ssh for that user.

Comment: Does this mean if I type ~/.ssh and it's not there, that ssh is not installed? If so, can you give or tell me where to find newbie-level instructions on how to install ssh?

Comment: No it just means that it is now yet used or not installed. You could simply try executing ssh if you get an error it is not installed